# Why custom validator not called on touch event in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have defined my custom Passwords validator like so:

```js
  confirmPassword(group: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    console.log('Validator invoked')    

    if ( group.get('password_verify')?.pristine === false ||
         group.get('password_verify')?.touched === true ) {
      return group.get('password_verify')?.value !== group.get('password')?.value ? {
        passwords: "Passwords mismatch"
      } : null
    }
    return null
  }
```

And used it in a standart way for FormGroup:

```js
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    phone: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    passwords: new FormGroup({
      password: new FormControl(''),
      password_verify: new FormControl('', this.myValidator)
    }, this.confirmPassword),
    first_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    last_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });
```

Problem is that console.log only invoked after i type something to 'password_verify' input.
While standart Validators.required, f.x., invokes even if you just focus/unfocus input, without inputting anything.

How do i make my custom validator behave in the same way ?
You may notice *this.myValidator* another custom validator w/o implementation. I tried making factory function ValidatorFn that returns () => {} to validate input(thinking may be that's a correct way), but no luck - validator won't be called on touch event.

**Angular v10**

Comment: Why you are you grouping password under passwords those should be simple two password fields with custom validators.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: @KamranKhatti because i need to use custom validator that checks both fields, that's wh i group them. i found this solution here on stack, it had like 300+ votes

Answer (score -1):

Try [Angular Custom Validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  phone: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
  password: new FormControl(''),
  password_verify: new FormControl('')
  first_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  last_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
}, { validators: confirmPassword });


export const confirmPassword: ValidatorFn = (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
 const password = control.get('password').value;
 const confirmPassword = control.get('password_verify').value;

 return password === confirmPassword ? null : { password_mismatch: true }
}
```

Comment: that is the same as in my code. i wrote about trying to make ValidatorFn as well. no luck. it won't trigger on touch event

Comment: @Anton create stackblitz example I can fix there.